# How to log HTTP request and response with ApolloClient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using both [ApolloClient](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) from 'apollo-client' and 'apollo-boost' libraries, like

```
 const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://www.myapp.no/api/',
  request: async (operation) => {

    console.log(operation)

    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: tokenHeader,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
  },
  onError: (error) => {
    if (error.graphQLErrors) {
      console.log('ApolloClient graphQLErrors')
      console.log(graphQLErrors)
    }
    if (error.networkError) {
      console.log('ApolloClient networkError')
      console.log(graphQLErrors)
    }
  }
})
```

The `operation` object only show `variables` and `query` information. How to log the actual HTTP requests and response under the hood?

I want to see the outgoing request headers and params, and the responses headers and status code

This seems like a very simple task but I've spent quite some time searching without any mentions about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome extension: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-devtools

Comment: That's fine for local development but I want to be able to log for monitoring a deployed site in production.